# Dealing with AutoFixture ConstructorInitializedMemberAssertion and a read-only property initialized inside the constructor

Tags: autofixture

I want to verify a class using `ConstructorInitializedMemberAssertion` and a read-only property `CreatedAt` that is initialized to a default value inside the constructor:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
   public MyClass(string name)
   {
      Name = name;
      CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
   }
   public string Name { get; private set; }
   public DateTime CreatedAt { get; private set; }
}
```

```cs
var fixture = new Fixture();
var ctorAssertion = fixture.Create<ConstructorInitializedMemberAssertion>();
ctorAssertion.Verify(typeof(MyClass));
```

This test throws the following exception:
`AutoFixture.Idioms.ConstructorInitializedMemberException: No constructors with an argument that matches the read-only property 'CreatedAt' were found`

I looked in the docs, but did not find any sample like that. I'm rather new with AutoFixture, so I may miss something.

How to exclude it from assertion or is there other way to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way by overloading the `ConstructorInitializedMemberAssertion.Verify(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)` method.

I ended up with something that looks like:

```cs
public class MyConstructorInitializedMemberAssertion : ConstructorInitializedMemberAssertion
{
    public override void Verify(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        if (propertyInfo.Name == "CreatedAt") { return; }
        base.Verify(propertyInfo);
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

Final code is smarter, though. This is just a quick sample with a hard-coded value.